# devise_token_auth Registrations failure - will not accept or skip "confirm_success_url"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have been unable to get "devise_token_auth" registrations working.

I have reached the point where I need some help/suggestions.  I have tried to find help/suggestions on the github page for devise_token_auth but have received no responses.

I am hoping that asking for help here might work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Summary -

I have installed and configured devise_token_auth according to what I understand is the correct process and have confirmed this setup as far as I can via the "help me" and google search..  I am trying to create a User with the expectation that I will receive a confirmation link email.

1. If I include the parameter "confirm_success_url"-
   using this -

   curl -XPOST http://localhost:7000/api/v1/auth --data "email=mail@mail.com&password=123456789&password_confirmation=12345678&confirm_success_url='http://localhost:7000/'" -o results.html

I receive this -

```
ActionController::UnpermittedParameters in  DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create
found unpermitted parameter: confirm_success_url ... (much more stuff)
```

2. If I don't include the "confirm_success_url" 
   using this -

   curl -XPOST http://localhost:7000/api/v1/auth --data "email=mail@mail.com&password=123456789&password_confirmation=123456789" -o results.html

I receive this -

```
{"status":"error","data":    {"id":null,"provider":"email","uid":"","name":null,"nickname":null,"image":null,"email":"mail@mail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},"errors":["Missing `confirm_success_url` param."]}
```

So basically-

1. Including "confirm_success_url" in the POST data  -> I receive an "unpermitted parameter" for "confirm_success_url"
2. Excluding  "confirm_success_url" in the POST data -> I receive a "missing parameter" for "confirm_success_url"

That is pretty much a no-win situation.

Here are my details -

Details -

routing.rb -

```
Iosrails::Application.routes.draw do
namespace :api  do
    scope :v1 do
    mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
end
end
end
```

application_controller.rb -

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

user.rb -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules.
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
      :confirmable, :omniauthable
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

development.log - (with confirm_success_url in POST)

```
Started POST "/api/auth" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-12 14:38:54 -0400
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"mail@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",    "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "confirm_success_url"=>"http://localhost:7000/"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
** [Airbrake] Notice was not sent due to configuration:         
  Environment Monitored? false         
  API key set? false

ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameter:     confirm_success_url): 
{ and much more}
```

It would seem that there might be an issue with the CSRF Token Authenticity (see log above) but I have everything set according to how I understand (:null_session) to avoid that issue

--
Additionally in an attempt to see if making confirm_success_url an permitted parameter would clear up the problem I also tried the following -

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :confirm_success_url
  end
end
```

and I now receive a new error -

```
unknown attribute 'confirm_success_url' for User.
```

Which I suppose makes sense since "confirm_success_url" is not a User model attribute.

So what should "confirm_success_url" be?  Should it be included/excluded?

Finally - I have added the following in "devise_token_auth.rb" with no change in the situation

```
default_confirm_success_url = "/"
```

Any help or pointers would really be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you figured this out? It seems you need to run some migrations to add the confirmable required fields.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to remove `:confirmable` from your devise model.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this in application_controller.rb or registrations_controller. This is generally how you specify/override these dependent paths with devise.

```
def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
  '/'
end
```

Comment: I believe devise_token_auth allows you to set the default_confirm_success_url in devise_token_auth.rb.  By setting that and updating the gem `gem "devise_token_auth", ">= 0.1.32.beta9"` I was able to make registrations work.  But it continues to throw the errors I list above when I include "confirm_success_url" in the POST data - which is the preferred method.  I (still) don't have any more ideas as to why that is not working.